# configuring log4j in a clustered environment

Tags: configuration, log4j, cluster-computing

We are using log4j for the logging functionality. The application is running in a Clustered environment. How can I configure log4j properties such that all the instances log to the same log file?

Comment: Nowhere near enough information. What does "clustered environment" mean?

Comment: Clustering is the concept of distributing the workload of a server across multiple machines. These are instances of the same application running is different machines or in other words different JDKs. I want to have a centralized log file for all the instances in the cluster.

Comment: Yes, we know what clustering means. We need to know what *kind* of clustering, it could mean a dozen different things. Clustering is a complex situation, and you're not going to be able to ask a meaningful question in 3 short sentences.

Comment: What I mean by clustering is, we have two unix boxes and the application instances are running on these unix boxes. I need to have common log file for both the instances. I hope things are clear.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have a directory dedicated for logging.  That directory can be on a network share (NFS, etc.) that is mounted to a location that is the same for both processes.  This could be as simple as mounting to the identical spot in the file structure or it could be done using environment variables ($LOGDIR) so each host could point to a different location in their local file structure.

The important thing is that the folder be shared so that multiple processes are writing to the same file.  The normal shared-resource restrictions apply though; make sure the file isn't locked by one host while preventing the other from writing, etc. Also, use an output pattern that includes hostname/process name/thread id.

Another approach I've used is a database appender that writes to a log table. No share needed but you still need to design the table considering the issues with multi-process logging.